# Parsing Wordpress JSON api

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse Wordpress JSON api to my Android application, but I am not able to get url of first thumbnail from here http://www.androidaci.net/api/get_post/?post_id=4559 so the result should be this string :

```
http:\/\/www.androidaci.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/Galaxy_S5_mini_water_resistance_test-150x150.jpg
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Check out this website,http://json.parser.online.fr/ . Paste the json string into that site and it will format it for you so you can see the structure of and parse accordingly.

Comment: this helped :) now I can see it thanks :)